# Current Transformer HWCT004 and ESP32

Tags: current, transformer, current-measurement, esp32, current-transformer

I am trying to measure the AC current up to 20A flowing through a current transformer using ESP32 Development board. I have a bunch of these [cheap current transformers from Aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33052338056.html). But I am completely clueless how do I interface this with the ESP32.

The AC flowing through the current transformer is 50Hz so the output current will also be 50Hz signal. Now if I pass it through a suitable burden resistor, the output voltage will also be 50Hz AC. but I can not measure this AC with an ESP32. Does anyone has any reference circuit which I can refer to?

I could not find a separate datasheet. Turns Ratio: 1000:1 Input: 0 to 50 A Output: 0 to 50 mA Load: 50 Ω Ratio error: 0.1% Phase difference: < 20 ' The linear range: 5%-120% Dielectric strength: 1000M Ω /500V/min Operating temperature: -25 -+75 centigrade Storage temperature: -40 -+80 centigrade Case material: flame retardant PBT/ environmental friendly flame retardant ABS

Comment: You might have damaged the ESP32 if you didn't wire the burden correctly so, show how you connected it please.

Comment: Great, can you post a scope output of the current transformer?